# What is the difference between list.add and list[0] = ""; in list<>?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between list.add and list[0] = ""; in the code bellow?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Hello");
        list[1] = "World";
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: in your example, list[1] does not exist.

Comment: You haven't really ran and tested your code before posting, this is why you are being downvoted and your question may be closed down soon.

Answer (score 4):

`list.Add` adds an item of type string to the end of the list.

`list[0] = ""` modifies the item at index 0 to a new value of ""

But, as in the code example you've posted, you call `list[1] = "World"`.

That line will get an **IndexOutOfBoundsException** because indexing is zero-based and list[1] points to the second item in the list which of course does not exist.